# hive on windows 7 desktop

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

Can I install apache hive on my windows 7 desktop and use it without hadoop? This will be just for testing and development purpose. Not sure if there is a way to run it in local mode without hadoop.

Comment: You'll definitely need hadoop installed.  If you want a dev environment I'd suggest installing hadoop w/Hive on a sandbox or renting an amazon instance.

Comment: I believe  Hive runs only on Linux, so you'll need cygwin installed on windows. try installing Hive over cygwin on windows and run in local mode I think it should work - I haven't tried this and cannot guarantee it will.

Comment: Hi Prahalad, 

I will try this and will let you know the outcome.